# Binary xml file line error inflating class unknown when use custom library

Tags: android, xml, class, inflate

I have made my custom view . It includes 2 libraries . The first is StickyListHeader . The second is PullToRefresh . Problem is my app was running perfectly fine on first load . After I back to home screen and come back its crash . It work fine on Android 2.3 . But on Android 4.0 and above it crash always .
This is my xml class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <thanhnd.lib.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my logcat

```
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{thanhnd.sample/thanhnd.sample.PullToRefreshListViewSampleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at thanhnd.sample.PullToRefreshListViewSampleActivity.onCreate(PullToRefreshListViewSampleActivity.java:20)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     ... 11 more
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     ... 22 more
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at thanhnd.lib.PullToRefreshListView.setHeaderPadding(PullToRefreshListView.java:250)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at thanhnd.lib.PullToRefreshListView.onScrollChanged(PullToRefreshListView.java:408)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1278)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.widget.AbsListView.setOnScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1265)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView.<init>(StickyListHeadersListView.java:112)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView.<init>(StickyListHeadersListView.java:105)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at thanhnd.lib.PullToRefreshListView.<init>(PullToRefreshListView.java:85)
11-20 15:56:41.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     ... 25 more
```

Comment: misspelling . It has work perfect on first load . But when I go out and comeback . It crash